# Import PNG in indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, png

I'm exporting some elements out of photoshop CC 2014 using the new 'extract assets', witch is very handy because i can just select the layer i want and export it. I export the white logo as a png. When i then try to import it in indesign CC 2014, the image converts to black and white and not transparant ( i can see it in the info panel where it says: 'transparancy : no'). 
[image]

Any idea's on how to fix this?

Comment: I just tried this and was not able to replicate your issue; everything worked perfectly, for me.  What settings did you use for the png, when extracting, and how are you importing it into InDesign?

Comment: I downvoted your question because you have no explanation of what you've done and so far the two answers from two different users that have tried to help you, you have said that you've already done that or tried it.  So instead of commenting maybe edit your question to include what you've done so you could get an answer that may actually help you.

Comment: I followed the suggestions about exporting the layer as psd by @pute . I also said that was helpfull.. Then i tried the 24 bit method and that did not work. This was all after the question. But i'll edit my question now , sorry, kindoff new to all this

Answer (score 4):

The short answer here is, "Don't do that." There are three reasons why:

- Extract Assets is designed and intended as part of a web workflow. It is not actually useful for print.
- PNG is not a print format. It was created for the web and remains a terrific on-screen image format, but there are far better formats for print.
- A layered PSD can be placed directly in InDesign, and the layers you don't need can be turned off (or the Layer Comp you want can be turned on) for each instance where the PSD is placed. Going through an extra step of generating a derived image to then place *that* in InDesign is, quite literally, a waste of production time, especially when there are revisions to the original.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried changing the import options? Check `Show import options` in the `Place` file dialog before importing. Maybe `Use transparency information` is disabled.

Comment: Tried this, did not help, thanks for pointing out the menu though!

Comment: @StefHamerlinck If you tried this than maybe you should edit your question to include more information so that you won't receive good answers you've already tried.  We arent mind readers ;)

Comment: Hi Matt, i ment this in an other way! I ment to say: i tried it after you suggested it and it did not help, i still got the same PNG with black and white borders and no tranparancy

Answer (score 2):

Well first you gotta make sure that its a 24 bit PNG. In order to do that you can just name the layer that you want to make the asset of like this:

> assetname.png24

But in general i gotta say that PNG is primarily a web-format. Of course i don't know what you are trying to accomplish, but since there is better options to make webgraphics than InDesign i just assumed you're doing Printwork. 
If that is the case i strongly recommend you to use transparent **TIF** of **PSD**.

I also guess you are *NOT* doing that, because you want to extract several layers at once? just activating layers and quickly saving different psd's isn't that much work either and you'll get a more satisfying result.

If it's got to be done with image-asset extraction, you could also try gifs.
Therefore just name your layers

> layername.gif

hope this helps. sry for bad english.

Comment: I actually was using extract assets because i thought it was the fastest way, and i love using the 'scaling' options (x2) and such. I now created it as smart object and saved the psd, then imported that in Indesign, that worked, so that's a way to achieve it. The 24-bit method did not work. Thank you !

Comment: The real problem is trying to use a web/mobile app production tool for something far away from its actual function. And gif, like png8, is an even worse format for print than png24.

Comment: "The real problem is trying to use a web/mobile app production tool for something far away from its actual function"  -true but also thats what makes great ideas sometimes :-)